# Issue With PreparedStatement with multiple paramsin java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using following code segment to retrieve limited number of raws from select query.

```
String query="SELECT * FROM smsmessage WHERE recipient = ? LIMIT ?";
   PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   prepStmt.setString(1,shortCode);
   prepStmt.setString(2,batchSize);
   ResultSet rs=prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

But it gives me following issue

```
 ERROR {com.axiata.plugin.ReceiveSMS.ReceiveSMSNotification} -  MySQL exception   
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
 You have an error in your SQL     syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 1
```

Is there any error in my code segment ? Can't I use multiple params as above ?

Comment: @M.Deinum Although, even if you could... the limit wouldn't be a string.

Comment: So How can I achieve this ? I want to pass two prams

Comment: Doh... Completely missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause requires an `int`.

```
prepStmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(batchSize));
```

[`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) from the MySQL documentation reads (in part)

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).